# Segue from UICollectionViewCell failing?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UICollectionView`:

```
class BoatMatchingGame: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

I also have a class for a different `ViewController` that I am trying to segue to:

```
class GameOutcome: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var gameOutcomeLabel: UILabel!
    var boatMatchingGame: BoatMatchingGame!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gameOutcomeLabel.text = gameOutcomeText
    }
}
```

In the `BoatMatchingGame` class I have the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let gameOutcome = segue.destinationViewController as GameOutcome
    gameOutcome.boatMatchingGame = self;
}
```

The in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method, I want to perform the `segue`:

```
switch indexPath.item {
    case 14:
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Quit Matching Game", sender: self)
```

I have set the identifier `"Quit Matching Game"` in the storyboard. When I run the program and select `cell` at `indexPath` 14, I get the following error: `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0)` on this line in a thread: `0x202ebd8:  popl   %ebp`

Note: I do have a label that is changing every second in this cell.

Thank you!

Here is the entire thread:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x2080ba0:  pushl  %ebp
0x2080ba1:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x2080ba3:  movl   0x8(%ebp), %eax
0x2080ba6:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x2080ba8:  je     0x2080bbb                 ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 27
0x2080baa:  movl   0xc(%ebp), %ecx
0x2080bad:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x2080baf:  nop    
0x2080bb0:  cmpl   %ecx, %edx
0x2080bb2:  je     0x2080bd8                 ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 56
0x2080bb4:  movl   0x4(%edx), %edx
0x2080bb7:  testl  %edx, %edx
0x2080bb9:  jne    0x2080bb0                 ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 16
0x2080bbb:  calll  0x2080bc0                 ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 32
0x2080bc0:  popl   %eax
0x2080bc1:  leal   0x38262(%eax), %ecx
0x2080bc7:  movl   0x7748c(%eax), %eax
0x2080bcd:  movl   %ecx, 0x8(%eax)
0x2080bd0:  movl   $0x0, 0xc(%eax)
0x2080bd7:  int3   
0x2080bd8:  popl   %ebp
0x2080bd9:  retl   
0x2080bda:  nopw   (%eax,%eax)
```

Comment: @vacawama I dragged the segue from the `BoatMatchingGame` ViewController to the `GameOutcome` ViewController in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't actually declared or initialized the `gameOutcomeText` variable you use in `GameOutcome`'s `viewDidLoad`.

If you set `gameOutcomeText` within the `BoatMatchingGame` class, you can access it using the instance of `BoatMatchingGame` you passed into the `GameOutcome` view controller, like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gameOutcomeLabel.text = boatMatchingGame.gameOutcomeText
}
```

Comment: Sorry; I forgot to mention that `gameOutcomeText` is stored as a `public var`. I tried moving it into the class and using this method, but I still get the same error.